# Hide Shipping Method Title from Order Summary

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods, totals, order-summary

In order summary (Cart page), Shipping Method is displayed as:

**(Method Name - Method Title)**

Is it possible to remove Method Title and display just the Name?

[image]

Comment: yeah just override the summary template

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please override your file

> vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/summary/shipping.js

to

> /app/design/frontend/Vendor/ThemeName/Magento_Checkout/web/js/view/summary/shipping.js

Change Below Function Your Theme

```
 getShippingMethodTitle: function () {
        var shippingMethod,
            shippingMethodTitle = '';

        if (!this.isCalculated()) {
            return '';
        }
        shippingMethod = quote.shippingMethod();

        if (typeof shippingMethod['method_title'] !== 'undefined') {
            shippingMethodTitle = shippingMethod['method_title'];
        }

        return shippingMethod ? shippingMethodTitle : '';
    },
```

Comment: this overriding in checkout summary as well.

Answer (score 3):

The above answer detailed by Mohit will work fine, although instead of over-riding the shipping.js file, best to add the changes as a Mixin.

If you aren't familiar with Mixins, best to read up about it in Magento's documentation: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js_mixins.html

Create the following file:
app/design/frontend/VendorName/ThemeName/Magento_Checkout/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/shipping': {
                'Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/shipping-mixin': true
            },
        }
    }
};
```

Then create the Mixin file. Best practise to keep the path the same as the file you are extending, and then adding -mixin to the end.

app/design/frontend/VendorName/ThemeName/Magento_Checkout/web/js/view/summary/shipping-mixin.js

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/abstract-total',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
    'Magento_SalesRule/js/view/summary/discount'
], function ($, _, Component, quote, discountView) {
    'use strict';

    var mixin = {

        /**
         * @return {*}
         */
        getShippingMethodTitle: function () {

            var shippingMethod,
                shippingMethodTitle = '';

            if (!this.isCalculated()) {
                return '';
            }
            shippingMethod = quote.shippingMethod();

            if (!_.isArray(shippingMethod) && !_.isObject(shippingMethod)) {
                return '';
            }

            if (typeof shippingMethod['method_title'] !== 'undefined') {
                shippingMethodTitle = shippingMethod['method_title'];
            }

            return shippingMethodTitle ?
                shippingMethodTitle : '';
        },

    };

    return function (target) {
        return target.extend(mixin);
    };
});
```